# flask-wtf behavior with 2 forms in view

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

example 2 forms in one page:

```
<form name="form_A" class="form-inline" action="/" method="post">
{{form_A.hidden_tag()}}
    {{form_A.name(type="text", class="form-control")}}
    <input type="submit" name="form_A" id="form_A" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="FORM_A">
</form>

<form name="form_B" class="form-inline" action="/" method="post">
{{form_B.hidden_tag()}}
    {{form_B.name(type="text", class="form-control")}}
    <input type="submit" name="form_A" id="form_A" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="FORM_B">
</form>
```

and router:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form_A = ExampleForm1(request.form)
    form_B = ExampleForm1(request.form)
    if form_A.validate_on_submit():
        ...
    if form_B.validate_on_submit():
        ...
```

any submit button (FORM_A or B) call form_A.validate_on_submit() and form_B.validate_on_submit() together(!). why?
and how to submit only one form in this case?

EDIT:

i solve this problem just add check data any field and use is_submitted method:

```
if form_A.is_submittied() and form_A.name.data:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When using more than one form, you need to give each form a prefix:

```
form_A = ExampleForm1(request.form, prefix='form_a')
form_B = ExampleForm1(request.form, prefix='form_b')
```